# change default location when creating an external table in hive

Tags: hive, location, external, create-table

I would like to create an `external table` in `hive` from a `view` and change the default `location`:

```
CREATE external TABLE market.resultats like v_ca_mag
LOCATION '/user/training/market/db/resultats';
```

The `table` is created and is `external` but the `location` is the default one `/user/hive/warehouse/market.db/resultats`.

Why is the `location` not taken into account?

I am using `cdh 5.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's a bug please open a jira to account for this issue.

As a work around once you are **done with creating external table** then **execute alter table statement to change the location of your newly created table to the desired location**.

```
hive> CREATE external TABLE market.resultats like v_ca_mag;
hive> alter table market.resultats set location 'hdfs://nnaddress/user/training/market/db/resultats';
```

Comment: Thanks for the informations, I ended up using the command `ALTER TABLE market.resultats SET LOCATION "hdfs:/user/training/market/db/resultats"` and it worked :).